# Store user-defined filters in database

Tags: django, django-models

I need to allow users to create and store filters for one of my models. The only decent idea I came up with is something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.CharField()    

class MyModelFilter(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Filter owner'))
    filter = models.TextField(_('JSON-defined filter'), blank=False)
```

So the filter field store a string like: 
`{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}`.
Then, somewhere in code:

```
filters = MyModelFilter.objects.filter(owner_id=owner_id)
querysets = [MyModel.objects.filter(**json.loads(filter)) for filter in filters]
result_queryset = reduce(lambda x, y: x|y, querysets)
```

This is not safe and I need to control available filter keys somehow. On the other hand, it presents full power of django queryset filters. For example, with this code I can filter related models. 
So I wonder, is there any better approach to this problem, or maybe a 3rd-party library, that implements same functionality?

**UPD:** 
`reduce` in code is for filtering with OR condition.

**UPD2:**
User-defined filters will be used by another part of system to filter newly added model instances, so I really need to store them on server-side somehow (not in cookies or something like that).

**SOLUTION:**
In the end, I used django-filter to generate filter form, then grabbing it's query data, converting in to json and saving it to the database.
After that, I could deserialize that field and use it in my FilterSet again. One problem that I couldn't solve in a normal way is testing single model in my FilterSet (when model in already fetched and I need to test, it it matches filter) so I ended up doing it manually (by checking each filter condition on model).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is actually what you want to do? Are your end users going to know what a filter is, or how to format the filter?

I suggest that you look into the Django-filter library (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/).

It will enable you to create filters for your Django models, and then assist you with rendering the filters as forms in the UI.

Comment: I actually already use django-filter. Is there a way to use it to extract filter data? The thing is, I really need to store filters in database, one way or another. They will be used by another part of system to filter newly added model instances (through API or using Celery), so I need not only render the filters or apply it to queryset (which django-filter does perfectly fine) but also store it somehow.